# Why does mapping out the Turtlebot 3 World from Gazebo in RViz SLAM GMapping result in a spontaneously cut off map?

Tags: ros, slam, gazebo-simu, rviz

Working with Visual Studio Code. WSL. Ubuntu 20.0.4. ROS Noetic.

Following this guide: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/slam_simulation/

I have tried to map this out on both my own and another laptop under the same environment and it has resulted in a similarly spontaneously split map. I'm new to ROS and was using this as an introduction to Gazebo simulation but I can't progress without having a proper map. I've tried messing with the gmapping parameters to little avail.

Ran:

(roscore)

Terminal 1

```
$ cd catkin_ws
$ source ./devel/setup.bash
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch
```

Terminal 2

```
$ cd catkin_ws
$ source ./devel/setup.bash
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_slam turtlebot3_slam.launch slam_methods:=gmapping
```

Terminal 3

```
$ cd catkin_ws
$ source ./devel/setup.bash
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch
```

The map builds as the robot reaches it with it's simulated LiDar everywhere except the perfect cut-off.

Anyone know how to avoid this [cut-off mapping?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGVGC.png)

Comment: I don't see how this is related to programming. Is it?

Comment: @Vega, the Robot Operating System is designed for robotic programming, so, I would guess so? There are also tags in Stack Overflow specifically for ROS, Gazebo, and RViz, so I was assuming it would be fine to ask a question relevant to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer but it doesn't really actually solve the problem. I ran map_saver and checked the .pgm file, which showed a completely rendered map, you are able to act as if the space exists even if it's not rendered. I believe it could have something to do with my GPU? Unsure. Regardless, it is properly recording the data of the map, it just isn't drawing it.

[pgm file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHdCT.png)